# Dynamic heading and table cells - tr and td in php

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem doing a dynamic table

My table structure is below:

```
======================================================================
tender_id | coc | datasheet | datecode | shelflife | Suppliername
======================================================================
   201    |  No |   Yes      |     Yes  |     No   |  Supplier1
   201    | Yes |   No       |     Yes  |     No   |  Supplier2
   201    | No  |   No       |     No   |     No   |  Supplier3
```

My expected result in PHP is

```
=============================================
 COC | Datasheet | Date Code | Supplier Name
=============================================
   -     Yes          Yes       Supplier1
  Yes    -            Yes       Supplier2
```

The results should only show if the value is 'Yes'. Even the heading should not be shown if all the values are 'No'. If One value is Yes and One value is No, then also the heading should be shown. For example in the above condition shelflife value is 'No' for all the suppliers. In this case even the heading it should not show. I have tried some script, but there is some problem.

This is the script i tried:

```
$sql_shelf = "SELECT tender_id, suppliername, coc, date_code, shelf_life , datasheet FROM comparitive_statement1 WHERE (coc='Yes' OR technical_compliance='Yes' OR date_code='Yes' OR shelf_life='Yes' OR datasheet='Yes') tender_id='$tender_id' group by suppliername";

    $result = mysql_query($sql_shelf) or die($sql_shelf."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    $i = 0;
    while ($list = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($i == 0){
    echo '<tr>';
    $sh = $list['shelf_life'];
    if ($sh=="No") {
    } else {
    echo '<td><b>Shelf Life</b></td>';
    }
      echo '</tr>';
      $i++;
      }

    echo '<tr>';
    $sl1 = $list['shelf_life'];
    if ($sl1=="No") {
    } else {
    echo "<td>{$list['shelf_life']}</td>";\
    echo "</tr>";
    }
     ++$i;
     }
```

The script is bit long, so i have just put the records related to shelflife.

Comment: why still using mysql?

Comment: i am revambing the already existing code. I will be changing to mysqli soon..

Comment: Table heading will display before while loop so you can control visibility via jquery. @SanjuMenon

Comment: How will i do that. Can u pls explain?

Answer (score 0):

Not saying that this is the most efficient way, but ...

```
// $data is the array you have after while ($list = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $data[]=$row; }
$data = [
    [ 'tender_id'=>201, 'coc'=>'No',  'datasheet'=>'Yes', 'datecode'=>'Yes', 'shelflife'=>'No', 'Suppliername'=>'Supplier1' ],
    [ 'tender_id'=>201, 'coc'=>'Yes', 'datasheet'=>'No',  'datecode'=>'Yes', 'shelflife'=>'No', 'Suppliername'=>'Supplier2' ],
    [ 'tender_id'=>201, 'coc'=>'No',  'datasheet'=>'No',  'datecode'=>'No',  'shelflife'=>'No', 'Suppliername'=>'Supplier3' ]
];

// remove all 'No' fields
$data = array_map(
    function($e) {
        return array_filter($e, function($f) { return 'No'!==$f; });
    },
    $data
);
/* => $data == [ 
    [ 'tender_id'=>201'datasheet'=>'Yes''datecode'=>'Yes''Suppliername'=>'Supplier1'],
    [ 'tender_id'=>201'coc'=>'Yes''datecode'=>'Yes''Suppliername'=>'Supplier2'],
    [ 'tender_id'=>201'Suppliername'=>'Supplier3']
]
*/

// now get an array of the keys present in any row
$fields = array_reduce(
    $data,
    function($carry, $item) {
        return $carry + array_keys($item);
    },
    []
);
/* => $fields == [ 'tender_id', 'datasheet', 'datecode', 'Suppliername']
  after the filter no row in $data contained an element 'shelflife'=>... 
  so it's also not present in $fields
*/

// make a "template" for empty fields
$fields = array_combine( $fields, array_fill(0, count($fields), ' - '));
/* => $fields == [ 'tender_id'=>' - ', 'datasheet'=>' - ', 'datecode'=>' - ', 'Suppliername'=>' - '] */

// now merge all rows in $data with this template, i.e. if a field is missing in a row add the default element
$data = array_map(
    function($e) use ($fields) {
        return $e + $fields;
    },
    $data
);
/* => $data == [
    [ 'tender_id'=>201, 'datasheet'=>'Yes','datecode'=>'Yes', 'Suppliername'=>'Supplier1'],
    [ 'tender_id'=>201, 'coc'=>'Yes', 'datecode'=>'Yes', 'Suppliername'=>'Supplier2', 'datasheet'=>' - '],
    [ 'tender_id'=>201, 'Suppliername'=>'Supplier3', 'datasheet'=>' - ', 'datecode'=>' - ']
]
*/
```

Now you can use $data *and* $fields to print your table.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql_shelf = "SELECT * FROM comparitive_statement1 WHERE (coc='Yes' OR datecode='Yes' OR shelflife='Yes' OR datasheet='Yes') group by suppliername";
$result = mysql_query($sql_shelf) or die($sql_shelf."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
$output="<table border='1'>";
$output .= "<tr>
    <td>COC</td>
    <td>Datasheet</td>
    <td class='deleteColumnDatecode'>DateCode</td>
    <td class='deleteColumn'>Shelf Life</td>
    <td>SupplierName</td></tr>";

$shelflife = false;
$datecode=false;
while ($list = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $output .= "<tr>
        <td>".$list['coc']."</td>
        <td>".$list['datasheet']."</td>
        <td class='deleteColumnDatecode'>".$list['datecode']."</td>
        <td class='deleteColumn'>".$list['shelflife']."</td>
        <td>".$list['Suppliername']."</td>
        </tr>";


    if( strcasecmp($list['shelflife'],"Yes")== 0) {
        $shelflife = true;
    }

    if( strcasecmp($list['datecode'],"Yes")== 0) {
        $datecode = true;
    }

 }

 if( $shelflife ){
     $output = str_replace( 'deleteColumn', '', $output);
 } 

 if( $datecode ){    
     $output = str_replace( 'deleteColumnDatecode', '', $output);
 } 

 echo $output;
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>comparitive_statement1</title>
    <style>
    td.deleteColumn,td.deleteColumnDatecode {
         display: none;
     }
    </style>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Varsha. Have a doubt. You have clarified the code for shelf_life. Can u pls add the code (deleteCoulumn) for datecode also. Because when iam adding the code for datecode, iam not getting output. Iam making a small mistake.

Comment: this answer looks copied from below given answer.

Comment: How to make datecode if not equal to zero. that is if its zero dont display

Comment: I am not getting it. so if datacode is "no" then don't display the row right ?

Comment: Instead of datecode is 'no', how will i make datecode!='0'  ?

Comment: strcasecmp(string1,string2) function returns:

    0 - if the two strings are equal
    <0 - if string1 is less than string2
    >0 - if string1 is greater than string2

Answer (score -2):

Hope this will solve your problem

```
    <?php
    $table_items = array("coc","datasheet","datecode","shelflife ");
    foreach($table_items as $value){
        $result = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM comparitive_statement1 WHERE ".$value." = 'Yes'"));
        if($result>0){
            echo "<td>".$result."</td>";
            }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me check it.

Comment: What if its returning 2 records. First record, coc='No' and second record coc='Yes'. In this case This will just omit COC. Am i correct?

Comment: this is only for the table heading part if all the values are no then the table heading is not displayed, sorry if I misunderstood your question.